# jq: Select using 2x seperate-level keys

Tags: jq

Using jq on JSON data ...

I'm trying to select records where FromPort is 80 and CidrIp is 0.0.0.0/0 within the same element of the record.

Here is the query:

```
cat data.json |jq -r '.SecurityGroups | .[] | select((.IpPermissions[] | .IpRanges[] | .CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0") and (.IpPermissions[] | .FromPort == 80))'
```

The data is below.

The results should only select Group3 but instead selects Group1 and Group3. I've tried various google searches but am unable to find the answer yet.

Very grateful for any help.

Data (data.json):

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "GroupName": "Group1",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 6789,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "GroupName": "Group2",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 443,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 6788,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "GroupName": "Group3",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 6789,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iteration inside your selection `.IpPermissions[] | .IpRanges[]` produces as many results as there are items in those arrays. For each `true` outcome, your `select` passes on the input in question (maybe several times). You need an aggregator like `any` or `all` to combine all the outcomes to one boolean result, so that `select` can pass on just either 1 or 0 copies of the corresponding input.

Furthermore, you iterate over `.IpPermissions[]` on **both** sides of the `and` in your condition which will produce a cartesian product of the outcomes.

Here is a solution that selects a group if there is **at least one** item in the `.IpPermissions` array that has a match for `.FromPort` **and at least one** match for `.CidrIp` in the `.IpRanges` array:

```sh
jq '
  .SecurityGroups[] | select(
    any(.IpPermissions[]; .FromPort == 80 and
      any(.IpRanges[]; .CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0")
    )
  )
' data.json
```

```json
{
  "GroupName": "Group3",
  "IpPermissions": [
    {
      "FromPort": 80,
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
        },
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "FromPort": 6789,
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xIWRZ_UDdN)

Answer (score 0):

You can use parenthesis `()` and `and` appropriately to filter like this: `(.FromPort==80 and (.IpRanges[] | .CidrIp=="0.0.0.0/0" ))`. By doing this, we make sure that **both** conditions are matched by an entry in `IpPermissions`.

Filter

```
.SecurityGroups | map(select(.IpPermissions[] 
| (.FromPort==80 and (.IpRanges[] | .CidrIp=="0.0.0.0/0" ))))
```

Input

```
{
  "SecurityGroups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "Group1",
      "IpPermissions": [
        {
          "FromPort": 80,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "FromPort": 6789,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
            },
            {
              "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "GroupName": "Group2",
      "IpPermissions": [
        {
          "FromPort": 443,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
            },
            {
              "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "FromPort": 6788,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "GroupName": "Group3",
      "IpPermissions": [
        {
          "FromPort": 80,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
            },
            {
              "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "FromPort": 6789,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "GroupName": "Group3",
    "IpPermissions": [
      {
        "FromPort": 80,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "IpRanges": [
          {
            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
          },
          {
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "FromPort": 6789,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "IpRanges": [
          {
            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/24"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now you can see only `Group3` is outputted.

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/qZvARp_5LE

Or you could use `any/2` as pmf suggested.

Filter

```
.SecurityGroups[] 
| select(any(.IpPermissions[]; .FromPort==80 
and any(.IpRanges[]; .CidrIp=="0.0.0.0/0")))
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/Rw2_dtzwUA

Comment: a related builtin is `all`.